# Creating a 3D variable from a 1D variable with NCO

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a 1D variable describing height in my NetCDF file.  I'd like to create an 3D variable that is uniform on the X and Y axes from this column of data.  Is there an easy way to do this in NCO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 1-D axes are named x and y and z, then construct a 3D field containing z that is uniform over x and y with [ncap2](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2):

```
ncap2 -s 'z_3D[z,y,x]=z' in.nc out.nc
```

Pretty cool, huh?

Comment: Cool, robust, well supported, and critical to many areas of modern science in my opinion.  Thank you!